# c# directshow multiple windows handling

Tags: c#, directshow

I have problem with handling multiple video windows in directshow.
I have app in c# that captures video stream of my webcam and sends it through infinite pin tree to 2 separate renderers. When I run the app each of the renderers gets its own VideoWindow. Now when I set VideoWindow Style I can see changes only on one of them (looks like it is 2nd renderer window). Secound window is not effected at all. What should I do to access both of them? There is only one graph to build entire thing. Is there a way to reference videowindow by the renderer not by the graph? I was looking around web but there is nothing thats was able to point me in to good direction.

Comment: Long shot is that you're not initializing second video render at all ([frequent](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d6a03c97-c210-40a7-a32d-c969c994fc7d/put-2-renderers-in-their-respective-ui-panel?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) problem). Your question is incomplete: you should [understand your graph](http://alax.info/blog/1678) first and include relevant information into the question, and you should also add some code.

Comment: Well I do initialize second renderer and I do have vidostream on both windows. Most of the code is from graphedit so that part should be fine. The problem is the IVideoWindow.Style becouse what I understand it has to point to graph and when it does only first of two video windows is effected by the style I set.

Comment: Graphedit does not produce code and your comment suggests that you don't understand the problem explained by linked (word "frequent" above; specifically words "... you need to query for `IVideoWindow` from respective filter object...") post. That is, my first comment above remains in good standing.

Comment: Grapheditplus does produce code ;) Ty for the answer I'll look at the link.

Comment: Roman your link does throw a bit of light at the problem and thank you for that. Unfortunately the code presented there as the author stated does not do the trick and it is in c++ with is a bit hard to use in my case (I'm writing this app in c#). I would like to know how to do it in C#.